# Continuous data with R

Tags: r, import, statistics, intervals, continuous

I am trying to import a matrice of two columns and 100 lines from excel to R. the first column is composed from continuous data in the form of interval ([100,150[, [150,200[,...) and the second is the corresponding frequency of each interval (responses number since the data are coming from a survey). when importing the table R show that the first column (class interval one ) is in form of a character and I can't change it to numeric form. How can I do this please? because I should proceed to a statistical analysis and I need to calculate the center of classes.

`

```
| X | FREQUENCY|
| -------- | -------- |
|[100,150)      5
 [150,200)      10
 [200,250)      20``your text`
```

Comment: Please add a short example what the expected output would be. Expressions can e.g. be parsed and evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

`[100,150)` is not numeric. It is a string representation of a number range. One way to work with this is to extract the numbers individually:

```r
nums <- lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(dat$X, "\\b\\d+\\b"), as.integer)
nums
# [[1]]
# [1] 100 150
# [[2]]
# [1] 150 200
# [[3]]
# [1] 200 250
dat <- cbind(dat, setNames(lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(nums, `[[`, i)), c("A", "B")))
dat
#           X FREQ   A   B
# 1 [100,150)    5 100 150
# 2 [150,200)   10 150 200
# 3 [200,250)   20 200 250
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(X = c("[100,150)", "[150,200)", "[200,250)"), FREQ = c(5L, 10L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot r2evans for your comment. Using this code "dat <- cbind(dat, setNames(lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(nums, `[[`, i)), c("A", "B")))" this error message apperead "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  les arguments impliquent des nombres de lignes différents : 4, 0" can you help me with this error please?

Comment: That suggests that your data has strings that do not contain two numbers. I'm working on the premise that the data you provide in the OP is an accurate representation, which it apparently is not. You likely need to fix `nums`, perhaps `nums <- lapply(nums, function(z) if (length(z) != 2) c(NA, NA) else z)`. It's a hack, hope it works on your real data.

Comment: exactly r2evans all my data contains intervals with two numbers and the data provided are a part from my dataset. but I note that when using the code " dat <- cbind(dat, setNames(lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(nums, `[[`, i)), c("A", "B")))" the output of "nums" is "list()" and in the environment space it is shown that "nums is a list of 0" I wonder if this output has any relation with the error message